# Is $\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} |x|^{s} \psi (x) dx$ continuous, where $\psi \in C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R})$ and has bounded support?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $$\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} |x|^{s} \psi (x) dx$$ continuous for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$, where $\psi \in C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R})$ and has bounded support?

The integrand is clearly continuous (except for $s<0$?) but I am unsure how integrating over $\mathbb{R}$ changes the overall continuity of the integrand, especially since $\psi$ has bounded support (is there a result from real analysis regarding this type of situation?) I do not think we can just take the derivative here and say the result implies continuity, either. Any suggestions?

Comment: For all $s\in\mathbb{R}$? How about negative $s$?

Comment: It is not continuous at $0$ if $s$ is negative

Comment: I just made an edit noting that. I also forgot to write $C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R})$ correctly, apologies. For those $s$ - can we still guarantee that the integral over $\mathbb{R}$ becomes continuous?

Comment: For $s>0$ you can use dominated convergence.

Comment: If $0$ is not in the support of $\psi$ then there is no problem with negative $s$.

Comment: By the Leibniz Integral rule, the derivative can be swapped with the integral so you can use the fact that the derivative exists in some places.

Comment: I think one should be OK when $s>-1$.

Comment: Yes, it will be continuous for any $s>1$, and any $s\in\mathbb{R}$ if $0$ is not in the support of $\psi$. More genrally, more values of $s$ can be allowed if $\psi(0) = 0$. For example, if $|\psi(x)|≤ |x|^a$ near $0$, then it will be continuous for $s>-1-a$.
I do not know if it would be continuous for all the values of $s$ such that the integral is defined? (i.e. is it "continuous to the right" of the minimal $s$ if there is one?)